# Problem getting fluentd to send loki the server hostname as Label on Windows Server

Tags: windows, fluentd, grafana-loki

I'm having problems getting the `hostname` added as a label to the messages that fluentd is sending to loki from my Windows Server using the `fluent-plugin-grafana-loki` plugin.

The following filter blocks do not work for me:

```xml
# 1

<filter loki>
  @type record_modifier
  prepare_value require 'socket'; $host = Socket.gethostname
  <record>
    hostname ${$host.downcase}
  </record>
</filter>

# 2

<filter loki>
  @type record_transformer
  enable_ruby true
  prepare_value require 'socket'; $host = Socket.gethostname
  <record>
    hostname ${$host.downcase}
  </record>
</filter>

# 3

<filter loki>
  @type record_modifier
  <record>
    host "#{Socket.gethostname}"
  </record>
</filter>
```

Comment: Did you try [`record_transformer`](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer) instead? The last one seems to be correct. However, I haven't tested it with `record_modifier` so I can't say for sure. The [first example](https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#example-configurations) from `record_transformer` docs demonstrates what you're trying to do.

Comment: Though the last one (#3) seems to be correct, it has `host` and not `hostname`. in `record` Have you verified that?